# How to bubble events in Silverlight usercontrols?

Tags: silverlight, events, user-controls, event-bubbling

I am trying to bubble an event from a child usercontrol to its parent.

The child usercontrol is a button inside a grid:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The parent usercontrol is composed by many instances of the child control:

```
<UserControl>
    <StackPanel>
        <customs:myButton CustomClick="something" />
        <customs:myButton CustomClick="something" />
        <customs:myButton CustomClick="something" />
        etc.
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In the child usercontrol I have defined:

```
    public delegate void CustomClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event CustomClickHandler CustomClick;
```

and the "inner" button handles the click event in this way:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CustomClick != null)
            CustomClick (sender, e);
    }
```

I've tried to check what it is going on, and I can see the Button_Click is invoked, CustomClick is not null and it gets executed. However nothing seems to happen, the code attached to that even in the parent usercontrol is not called.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,
Gianluca.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeking is called routed events. You can write your own custom ones or take a look at this [library](http://sl3routedevents.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought that was the problem, and I was trying to implement the bubbling thing on my own. Good that a lib already exists. However I think I am facing some other problem: I can move across the several instances of "myButton" with the "TAB" but I am not able to select or interact with none of them by using the mouse... do you think this issue is somehow related?

Comment: If your routedevents are specific to the mouse, you probably skip handling the event for the button itself. Does states work? like mousehover, etc.

Comment: A quick update. The parent usercontrol is inside another usercontrol (shellView contains keypad, which contains many keypadbutton). I can see that a mouseleftdown event is fired for the first Grid defined in shellView. if I try to catch the event in any of the other inner controls, it doesnt work. any idea?

Comment: set the e.Handled to false. Or something like that.

Comment: sadly not working. it's like if the uppermost control in the hierarchy is catching all events of the inner usercontrols....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have sorted this out, there were few problems though.

The first issue was caused by IsHitTestVisible. In some online articles it was said to set that property to false, in order to resolve some mouse-event related issues. I did so, but that was wrong because the element with that property set to false was "catching" the mouse events, and they were not arriving anymore to the inner usercontrols.

Secondly, in the most internal button (see my post above to understand the scenario), in order to get this to work, I've had to set the ClickMode="Hover" and to handle the MouseLeftButtonUp event. I'll try to use the standard click but I read somewhere that only certain event bubble up...

e.Handled did not need any change: I've checked and it was already false.

Neither I had to use any RoutedEvent library...

I cannot think of anything else I did to resolve the issue.

I guess this is all.

As always, if you have any suggestion, please feel free to add them here.

Cheers,
Gianluca.